# Pagination links for various lists using Spring-HATEOAS

Tags: java, reflection, spring, pagination

I'm using Spring HATEOAS to create some links on my REST API. However, the entities i'm returning are very close, so the code to generate the links are the same:

```
private Iterable<Link> getTemperatureSensorLinks(Links sensorLinks, Integer curPage) {

        Integer lastPage = sensorLinks.getLastPageNum();
        Integer firstPage = sensorLinks.getFirstPageNum();
        Integer nextPage = sensorLinks.getNextPageNum();
        Integer prevPage = sensorLinks.getPrevPageNum();

        List<Link> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(linkTo(methodOn(SensorController.class).getTemperatureSensor(firstPage)).withRel("first"));
        result.add(linkTo(methodOn(SensorController.class).getTemperatureSensor(lastPage)).withRel("last"));
        if(nextPage != null)
            result.add(linkTo(methodOn(SensorController.class).getTemperatureSensor(nextPage)).withRel("next"));
        if(prevPage != null)
            result.add(linkTo(methodOn(SensorController.class).getTemperatureSensor(prevPage)).withRel("prev"));

        return result;
    }
```

I have another method that's exactly the same, except that the method is `getMotionSensor(page)` instead of `getTeperatureSensor(page)`.

I tried to factor out the method like this:

```
private Iterable<Link> getSensorLinks(Links sensorLinks, Method m, Integer curPage) {

        Integer lastPage = sensorLinks.getLastPageNum();
        Integer firstPage = sensorLinks.getFirstPageNum();
        Integer nextPage = sensorLinks.getNextPageNum();
        Integer prevPage = sensorLinks.getPrevPageNum();

        List<Link> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(linkTo(m, firstPage).withRel("first"));
        result.add(linkTo(m, lastPage).withRel("last"));
        if(nextPage != null)
            result.add(linkTo(m, nextPage).withRel("next"));
        if(prevPage != null)
            result.add(linkTo(m, prevPage).withRel("prev"));

        return result;
    }
```

But then the calling methods get super ugly with reflection, and the checked exceptions thrown by Class.getMethod().

Is there a better way that I'm not seeing ?